# how to write a method to sum exactly abalance of savings account, not of both savings and current accounts in bank?

Tags: java

I'm creating a java project named Bank. SavingsAccount and CurrentAccount classes are subclasses of Account class. In a class Bank, which stores an information about accounts I have to create a method which prints the sum of balance amount for all SAVINGS accounts. How should I write the method to sum exactly a balance of savings accounts, not of both savings and current accounts?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Bank
{
    private ArrayList<Account> accounts;

    public Bank()
    {
        super();
        accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();

    }

    public void addAccount(Account theAccount)
    {
        accounts.add(theAccount);
    }

    public void getDescription()
    {
        for(Account account: accounts)
        {
            System.out.println("Name: " + account.getOwnerName() + "\nCode: " + account.getCode() + "\nBalance: " + account.getBalance());
        }
    }

    public double accountsSum()
    {
        double total = 0;
        for(Account acc: accounts)
        {
            total += acc.getBalance();
        }
        return total;
    }

    public void printSavingsBalance()
    {
            //?????    
    }
}



public class Account
{
    protected String code;
    protected String ownerName;
    protected double balance;

    public Account(String code,String ownerName, double balance)
    {
        this.code = code;
        this.ownerName = ownerName;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public String getCode(){return code;}

    public String getOwnerName(){return ownerName;}

    public double getBalance(){return balance;}

    public void setBalance(double newBalance)
    {
        balance = newBalance;
    }

    public void addMoney(double plusMoney)
    {
        balance += plusMoney;
    }

    public void withdrawMoney(double minusMoney)
    {
        balance -= minusMoney;
    }
}



public class SavingsAccount extends Account
{
    private int term;
    private double interestRate;

    public SavingsAccount(int term, double interestRate, String code, String ownerName, double balance)
    {
        super(code,ownerName,balance);
        this.term = term;
        this.interestRate = interestRate;
    }

    public int getTerm(){return term;}

    public double getInterestRate(){return interestRate;}

    public void setTerm(int newTerm)
    {
        term = newTerm;
    }

    public void setInterestRate(double newInterestRate)
    {
        interestRate = newInterestRate;
    }

    public double interestSize()
    {
        return balance*interestRate/365*term;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe just have two arraylists in your Bank class, one for each account type?

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide an alternative approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the instanceof to determine the type of the object and sum only when the type is Savings.

```
int totalBalance = 0;
for(Account account: accounts){
   if (account instanceof Saving) {
      totalBalance = totalBalance + account.getBalance();
   }
}
```

Comment: That's totally against polymorphism!!

Comment: @NarendraPathai - But ole Poly is a pretty conceited character.

Comment: It is true that instanceof is considered anti-polymorphic. The alternative is to use overriding but in this case it won't work. The other option is given by the posters below.

Comment: Please have a look at the updated answer for alternative approach. Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
private List<SavingsAccount> savingsAccounts;
private List<CurrentAccount> currentAccounts;

public addAccount(SavingsAccount account){

}

public addAccount(CurrentAccount account){

}
```

This would be much better to do. Then just iterate over the savings accounts and add the balance of all accounts. Introducing `accountType` and `instanceof` checks would be against polymorphism IMHO.

---

### A much cleaner approach with [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

```
public class Bank{

    private List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();

    public void add(Account account) {
        accounts.add(account);
    }

    public double getBalance(){
        AdditionAccountVisitor visitor = new AdditionAccountVisitor();
        for(Account account : accounts){
            account.accept(visitor);
        }

        return visitor.getSum();
    }
}

abstract class Account{
    private double balance;

    public Account(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public double getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }

    public abstract void accept(AccountVisitor visitor);
}

class SavingsAccount extends Account{

    public SavingsAccount(double balance) {
        super(balance);
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(AccountVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }

}

class CurrentAccount extends Account{

    public CurrentAccount(double balance) {
        super(balance);
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(AccountVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

interface AccountVisitor{
    public void visit(SavingsAccount savingsAccount);
    public void visit(CurrentAccount savingsAccount);
}

class AdditionAccountVisitor implements AccountVisitor{
    private double sum = 0.0;

    @Override
    public void visit(SavingsAccount savingsAccount) {
        sum += savingsAccount.getBalance();
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(CurrentAccount savingsAccount) {
        //do nothing
    }

    public double getSum(){
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: @HotLicks Who said this is simpler? This is a way to do with polymorphism. http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/visitor-pattern.html#! will be helpful.

Comment: Polymorphism for polymorphism's sake is simply stupid.  You use a technique because it produces better code faster and more cheaply, not because it suits some theory.

Comment: Above you've introduced two new classes and about 50 lines of code, all to avoid one instanceof.

Comment: @HotLicks Well lets agree to disagree :) But can I ask if you downvoted me? I think 50 lines of code today will pay tomorrow. Well if thats the case then why not just write whole code in a procedural way. Why bother creating classes? But that's just your way of doing things.

Comment: Well, I've been doing this for 40 years and I'm kind of set in my ways.  Of course at least 30 of those years I've been a fan of *appropriate* polymorphism, but then, over 30 years I've been exposed to an awful lot of *inappropriate* polymorphism, and all the other buzzwords like MVC and ERM and ECS and too many others to count.

Comment: Very nice answer @NarendraPathai I didn't think of doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

add an `accountType` field to the `Account` class, possibly of type enumeration (but also int etc). Then in the loop check if the account is of the desired type before adding the balance.

```
public void printSavingsBalance()
{
    double total = 0;
    for(Account acc: accounts)
    {
        if (acc.getType() == SAVINGS)
            total += acc.getBalance();
    }
    return total; 
}
```

or use 2 lists as suggested by @Narendra Pathai - depends on what else you want to do with the accounts and list

Comment: Please have a look at the updated answer for alternative approach. Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you're emotionally distraught at the thought of using `instanceof`, add a virtual method to your superclass and define it thusly in each subclass:

```
Savings:

String accountType() {
    return "Savings";
}

Checking:

String accountType() {
    return "Checking";
}
```